# nested axios call not updateing the state of reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

Here i am trying to fetch data from nested axios call. it's able get the response from two axios call.

> but i am not able to update prize_pool inside 2nd axios call. can
>   anyone help me on this

```
getAllLeague() {
    axios.get(BASE_URL + 'leagues').then((response) => {
        var arrData = [];
        for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {

            var data = {
                "leagueid": response.data[i].leagueid,
                "description": response.data[i].description,
                "itemdef": response.data[i].itemdef,
                "name": response.data[i].name,
                "tournament_url": response.data[i].tournament_url,
                "prize_pool" : ''
            }

            axios.get(BASE_URL + 'getTournamentPrizePool/' + response.data[i].leagueid).then((response) => {
                data.prize_pool = response.data.prize_pool;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            arrData.push(data);
        }

        console.log(arrData);
        this.setState({
            leagueList : arrData
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing an error when it's trying to set the value of prize_pool onto your data object?

Comment: no i am not getting any error. i am able to fetch the data from both the axios call. but it is not updating prize_pool

Comment: It might also be that you are pushing data into the array outside of the 2nd axios call. `arrData.push(data)` occurs first and then the callback for the 2nd network call kicks in.

Comment: not, that's not the problem. here some problem in callback.

Comment: by the time your `this.setState()` runs, all your `data.prize_pool` are still assigned to ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. need to use async and await at the time of API call in inner axios.

```
getAllLeague() {
        axios.get(BASE_URL + 'leagues').then(async (response) => {
            var arrData = [];
            for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {

                var data = {
                    "leagueid": response.data[i].leagueid,
                    "description": response.data[i].description,
                    "itemdef": response.data[i].itemdef,
                    "name": response.data[i].name,
                    "tournament_url": response.data[i].tournament_url,
                    "prize_pool" : ''
                }

                await axios.get(BASE_URL + 'getTournamentPrizePool/' + response.data[i].leagueid).then((response) => {
                    data.prize_pool = response.data.prize_pool;
                })

                arrData.push(data);
            }

            console.log(arrData);
            this.setState({
                leagueList : arrData
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause

```
 this.setState({
      leagueList : arrData
    });
```

will run before your 2nd axios complete. Try this. Using Promise.all is more cleaner. Hope it will help you.

```
getAllLeague() {
  axios.get(BASE_URL + 'leagues').then((response) => {
    const promises = response.data.map(item => {
      const formData = {
        "leagueid": response.data[i].leagueid,
        "description": response.data[i].description,
        "itemdef": response.data[i].itemdef,
        "name": response.data[i].name,
        "tournament_url": response.data[i].tournament_url,
        "prize_pool" : ''
      }
      const url = BASE_URL + 'getTournamentPrizePool/' + item.leagueid

      return axios.get(url).then(res => {
        return {
          ...formData,
          prize_pool: res.data.prize_pool,
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then(arrData => {
      this.setState({
        leagueList : arrData
      });
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```